# AbstractMethodError On a Dynamic Loaded Jar

Tags: java, plugins, dynamic

> I am loading a plug-in dynamically. Both the plug-in and the software
>   have been created by us.
>
> I have an Interface lets call it Foo. There is also FooImpl that just
>   implements that method But FooImpl is in the jar loaded dynamically 
>   `public interface Foo {
>       void write(..someArgument..) throws Exception; }`
>
> I have also a PluginLoader class here is the method
>
> ```
>  public
> Object loadPlugin(final String jarPath, final Class
> pluginInterface) {
>     try
>     {
>         final URI uri = new File(jarPath).toURI();
>         final URL url = uri.toURL();
> ```
>
> final URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
>     try
>     {
>          final Class<?> pluginClass = Class.forName("FooImpl", true, ucl);
>
>          // Verify if plugin implements plugin interface.
>          if (pluginClass.getInterfaces()[0].getName().equals(pluginInterface.getName()))
>          {
>           // Instantiate plugin.
>           return pluginClass.newInstance();
>
>          } }//[...] </code></pre>
>
> This part is actually working well i think so because after doing some
>   sysout on the pluginClass  i notice:
>  the .getMethods() = 
>   [public void FooImpl.write(..someArgumentType..) throws Exception, 
>   public abstract void some.package.Foo.write(..someArgumentType..)
>   throws Exception]
>
> the .getGenericInterfaces() = [interface some.package.Foo]
>
> But when i try to call the method write here is what i get
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: FooImpl.write(..SomeArgumentType..;)V
>   
>  I dont know why there is a ";" and a "V"
>
> So basically i think that it try to call the interface method instead
>   of the implemented one. So i'm wondering What is going on!
>
> As usual, Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Are you calling the write method via the instance ie `((Foo)instance).write(??)` or via reflection?

Comment: final PluginLoader loader = new PluginLoader();
final Object loadedLayer = loader.loadPlugin(pathToPlugin, Foo.class);
this.plugin = (Foo) loadedLayer; I am really sorry for the format I am not used with stackoverFlow

Comment: if(pluginClass instanceof pluginInterface) ) - shouldn't this be your interface check?

Comment: You are probably right. This would be a better way to verify if the class loaded implements the interface. Unfortunately this is not the OP question. But i will change the check asap. Thank for noticing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AbstractMethodError suggests that your code is trying to use a different version of a class at runtime compared to the class it was originally built against. You need to ensure that in your execution environment, there isn't a rogue version of your interface implementation on the classpath.

Comment: Humm,The only time i load the plug in is via the pluginLoader class describe in the OP. I also have to give the path to the jar where i load the implementation. But i will try to verify what is loaded by the classLoader.

Comment: Sir, you are officially my hero. I indeed had a rogue instance in my class loader. For people who have any kind of same problem just use the -verbose:class  in the jvm option and investigate for a wild rogue instance of the class. Thank alots